# Visual Studio Cordova and SalesforceMobileSDK

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, salesforce-ios-sdk

Would anybody have a sample project using the SalesforceMobileSDK?

Trying to achieve something similar to https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit - in Visual Studio, but I'm getting stuck in the Salesforce authentication code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Samples

I found this guy, he has some sample projects for ios and android.